# Define a function to take a string method name and applicably-typed parameter, and then call the method

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, types

I am looking to define a function which:

1. Takes a key of the string prototype as an argument, which points to a function
2. Also takes an argument with which to call said function
3. Then, putting it all together, calls the method using the given argument.

This sounds simple enough, and in vanilla Javascript, could be implemented very easily:

```js
function callFunction(key, param) {
    const myImportantString = "password123"
    return myImportantString[key](param);
}

callFunction('slice', 8) // => '123'
```

Where I'm struggling is in trying to implement this in Typescript. I have type functions that appear to work in isolation, but Typescript seems to get 'lost' when combining it all.

Here are my type helpers, which I've tested individually and can't find any issues with.

```
// yields a union of all keys that point to a function that takes one argument
type Callable<R> = keyof {
    [K in keyof R]: R[K] extends ((arg: any) => any) ? K : never
}[keyof R];

// yields the type of the first argument expected by a function
type FirstArgument<T> = T extends ((arg: infer U) => any) ? U : never;

// yields the return type of a function
type ReturnType<T> = T extends (...args: any) => (infer U) ? U : never;
```

With these, it should seemingly work to define my function like so:

```js
function callFunction<T extends Callable<String>>(key: T, param: FirstArgument<String[T]>): ReturnType<String[T]> {
    const importantString = 'password123';
    return importantString[key](param);
}
```

However, Typescript complains under `importantString[key(` that:

> This expression is not callable. Each member of the union type '(() => IterableIterator) | ... 40 more ... | ((index: number) => string | undefined)' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.

Interestingly, replacing `String` with a generic object and `importantString` with a parameter seems to work, as in:

```js
function callFunction<Q extends {[key: string]: any}, T extends Callable<Q>>(object: Q, key: T, param: FirstArgument<Q[T]>): ReturnType<Q[T]> {
    return object[key](param);
}

// note the 'as String' needed to prevent `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [key: string]: any; }'.`
callFunction('password123' as String, 'slice', 8)
```

However, curiously enough, trying to make it *less* generic is what actually breaks it, as in my example above.

This seems like a fairly simple task, but I'm at a loss as to how to proceed. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: [Lazy way](https://tsplay.dev/Nnb5VN)

Comment: @caTS - Yeah, that's basically what I've ended up doing too to be able to hush Typescript while I get on with everything else. It's better than nothing, but not an ideal solution of course, especially in functions more complicated than this MRE.

Comment: Ah, looks like another instance of [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) where the recommended approach is [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WvGznw).  If that meets your needs I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing? (Pls mention @jcalz in a reply to notify me)